# PostgreSQL Cast the output of the non-recursive term to the correct type

Tags: postgresql

I have a following PostgreSQL query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE disease_tree AS
(
SELECT ref_disease_id, uid, parent, level, NULL AS subtype, NULL AS specific_subtype
FROM ref_disease
WHERE parent IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT d.ref_disease_id, d.uid, d.parent, d.level,  
  CASE 
      WHEN d.level = 2 THEN d.uid
      ELSE dtr.subtype END AS subtype,
  CASE 
      WHEN d.level = 3 THEN d.name
      ELSE NULL END AS specific_subtype
FROM ref_disease As d
INNER JOIN disease_tree AS dtr
ON d.parent = dtr.uid
)
select ref_disease_id, uid, level, subtype, specific_subtype from disease_tree
```

So far everything works fine. But according to my application logic I have to return `d.uid` instead of `d.name` at the following line:  `WHEN d.level = 3 THEN d.name`

So the new query looks like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE disease_tree AS
(
SELECT ref_disease_id, uid, parent, level, NULL AS subtype, NULL AS specific_subtype
FROM ref_disease
WHERE parent IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT d.ref_disease_id, d.uid, d.parent, d.level,  
  CASE 
      WHEN d.level = 2 THEN d.uid
      ELSE dtr.subtype END AS subtype,
  CASE 
      WHEN d.level = 3 THEN d.uid
      ELSE NULL END AS specific_subtype
FROM ref_disease As d
INNER JOIN disease_tree AS dtr
ON d.parent = dtr.uid
)
select ref_disease_id, uid, level, subtype, specific_subtype from disease_tree
```

but it fails with a following error:

```
ERROR:  recursive query "disease_tree" column 6 has type text in non-recursive term but type character varying overall
LINE 3: ..._disease_id, uid, parent, level, NULL AS subtype, NULL AS sp...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Cast the output of the non-recursive term to the correct type.
********** Error **********

ERROR: recursive query "disease_tree" column 6 has type text in non-recursive term but type character varying overall
SQL state: 42804
Hint: Cast the output of the non-recursive term to the correct type.
Character: 107
```

How to cast the output and fix it ?

Comment: Cast the null value: `null::character varying`

Answer (score 3):

A `case` expression returns a single type, derived from among the types in the `then` and `where` clauses.  By default, `NULL` is text (I think).

Your case would appear to be mixing types.  So, convert the values.  Postgres has the nice short-hand of `::<type>`:

```
(CASE WHEN d.level = 2 THEN d.uid::text
      ELSE dtr.subtype::text
 END) AS subtype,
```

You want to do the conversion within the `CASE`, otherwise you may get a run-time error as the string is attempted to be converted to an number.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Won't that attempt to convert the string value to a number first?  That is likely to cause an error.

Comment: The cause of the error is that the `null` values in the non-recursive part do not have the correct type